# Plotting 2D Hilbert Spectrum in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, spectrum

I want to create a 2d plot of hilbert spectrum. What i want is a time vs frequency plot, where the amplitude of the signal is represented by color changes in the plot.

What i have done is  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTAZy.png), but I need it to look like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5f43.jpg).

Thank you in advance

EDIT:

I have the values of amplitude and instantaneous frequency over time, that i have produced using Hilbert Huang Transform. 
Let's say we only use the first IMF, and we have 100 samples. Then what we have is:

```
    instantaneous_frequency = [f1 f2 f3 ... f100]
    instantaneous_amplitude = [a1 a2 a3 ... a100]
    time = [t1 t2 t3 ... t100]
```

What i need is a way to plot them like the second image, without using the spectrogram function, since it uses STFT and I have already applied HHT.

The code for producing the first plot is:

```
Time_Window = 1:101;
signal= rand(1,101);
hilb = hilbert(signal);
inst_amp = abs(hilb);
inst_th = angle(hilb);
inst_freq = diff(a_inst_th)/(1/256)/(2*pi); %instantaneous frequency 
%inst_freq = remove_outliers(inst_freq,Time_Window(1:end-1)); 
inst_freq(end+1) = inst_freq(end); % This is done due to diff()
plot(Time_Window*4,inst_freq,'k.','MarkerSize',5)
```

Comment: Posting the code for what you have done would be useful in getting you toward your goal...

Comment: Added sample code in the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a MATLAB function to produce a [spectrogram](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html), which looks a lot like what you want. See if that solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunetly spectrogram uses STFT to find the spectrum. I already have the values of frequency, amplitude and time, that i have produced using Hilbert-Huang Transform. What i need is a way to plot them like the 2nd image.

Comment: In that case you can use pcolor: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html
Set a colormap appropriately, and you probably don't want an edge color.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using pcolor, but cant make it work. What i do is `pcolor(Time_Window*4,a_inst_freq,diag(a_inst_amp))`
 and i get is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F9PEh.png).